# Unable to change boot method in Microsoft DNS

Tags: domain-name-system

I am experimenting with Microsoft DNS, and have knowledge of Bind. I am trying to boot the server from boot file. Problem is that when I change the boot method, as mentioned here(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772388.aspx), an error appears, "Boot method cannot be set. The boot from file option cannot be selected because there are one or more active-directory registered zones."

To solve this I have deleted both the zones from the server and have restarted it but the same error still appears.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see this happening is if you installed Active Directory along with DNS. When you have an Active Directory-integrated DNS server, it can't boot from a file. It has to stay AD-integrated. You can click through the properties of each zone and change them from "Active Directory-integrated" to standard, then try again, but consider the adverse of effects that would have on AD. Perhaps you didn't mean to install AD at all in the first place, but just DNS?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try this and respond back if this works.